# How to change the value of a JSON file using arithmetics?

Tags: javascript, json, discord.js

Sorry if the title doesn't make sense.

Basically, in my `case.JSON` file I have the following:

```js
{
  "case": 0
}
```

I want it so that when the code is ran `case` goes up by `1` in value, and I can assign that anywhere so (discord.js example) in a Rich-embed I can put the caseNumber at the footer/field/description.

I had a hard time trying to have this make sense so any help would be appreciated.

I want to use Node FS to save it to my JSON file every time I restart my code
So I want it to update it everytime.

These are my [previous attempts](http://codebin.herokuapp.com/?s=5f91e571f8aa3b0004000001):

```js
// console.log('Starting...')
var fs = require('fs');
var cases = fs.readFileSync('case.json');
var caseUp = cases + 1;
var translateCases = JSON.parse(caseUp);

var data = JSON.stringify(translateCases)
fs.writeFile('case.json', data, finished);
function finished(err){
    console.log('All set.');
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////// I've tried these 2 seperately ^ v


// console.log(translateCases);

console.log('Starting...')
var caseJSON = require('./case.json');
var caseTest = caseJSON.case[0 + 1]
caseTest = 0;
caseTest += 1;
// caseTestTranslate = JSON.parse(caseTest)

var actualNumber = JSON.stringify(caseTest)
fs.writeFile('case.json', actualNumber, finished)
function finished(err){
    console.log('All good.')
}

console.log(caseTest)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  If you haven't done so, please visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) here.

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you want to do.  Do you want to update the file on the disk every time a block of code is run.  Or do you just want to updated a value in memory?

Comment: @ScottSauyet I want to use Node FS to save it to my JSON file every time I restart my code, I'm not sure what you mean by "update the file on the disk/update a value in memory". Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: You answered it.  You want to update an actual file every time.  Can you share what you've tried so far?

Comment: http://codebin.herokuapp.com?s=5f91e571f8aa3b0004000001 < I've tried this currently, with the help of tutorials and just messing around with it myself.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include this information.  StackOverflow questions are meant to be (at least mostly) self-contained.

Comment: I did that, sorry for not doing it earlier!

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion.  I meant to edit it so that it includes the code you've tried.

Comment: No worrries. I just updated.

Comment: I meant the way I just updated it.  Actually include the relevant code directly in the question.  It's fine for now, now that I've done it.  But next time, while links are fine to offer more context, the important code should be included in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you were almost there! look closely to the order:

```js
var cases = fs.readFileSync('case.json'); // is a string
var caseUp = cases + 1; // string + number => string, which is not what you wanted
// for this case, you can parse the filecontents first with JSON.parse on the file contents
```

or, what you did in the code below

```js
var caseJSON = require('./case.json'); // now caseJSON is directly parsed as an object
// so caseJSON.case contains the value you want to increment
```

with this approach, it would look something like this:

```js
var fs = require('fs');

console.log('Starting...')
var caseJSON = require('./case.json');
var caseJSONIncremented = { case: caseJSON.case + 1 }

var fileContent = JSON.stringify(caseJSONIncremented)
fs.writeFile('case.json', fileContent, finished)

function finished(err){
    console.log('All good.')
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been trying to figure this out for months, I was to "scared" to ask for help though. Thanks soo much!

Comment: @Craig: Don't be scared to ask for help!  There are usually people willing and able to offer it.

Comment: @Craig np, glad to help you out ;) pls checkmark the solution so others know the problem is solved

Comment: @Craig - you need to keep in mind that JSON is a text _representation_ of javacript objects; as text it needs to be _parsed_ to turn it into actual Javascript — `require` as Raymonzut shows does that parsing, or the more explicit `let object = JSON.parse(theText)` also parses.

Answer (score 2):

Raymonzut already showed a fix for your second attempt.  Here are some annotations on your first one:

> ```js
> var fs = require('fs');
> var cases = fs.readFileSync('case.json');
> ```

First off, in modern JS, `var` is generally not recommended.  Use `const` when you can and `let` when you have to.

If you're going to use the Sync APIs, you probably want to wrap in `try-catch` to handle any issues with opening the file.

Note that now `cases` will hold a string (if there was no error.)  You will have to call `JSON.parse` on this result to return an object.  So these two lines are out of order:

> ```js
> var caseUp = cases + 1;
> var translateCases = JSON.parse(caseUp);
> ```

But you can't just switch them, since your types won't line up.  My suggestion is below.

> ```
> var data = JSON.stringify(translateCases)
> fs.writeFile('case.json', data, finished);
> function finished(err){
>     console.log('All set.');
> }
> ```

I would not recommend combining the sync and async APIs in the same block of code.

An (untested) fix would look like this:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

try {
  const str = fs.readFileSync('case.json')
  const obj = JSON.parse(str)
  // This does not change obj, but creates a clone with an updated version of `cases`
  const updatedObj = {
    ... obj
    cases: (obj.cases || 0) + 1
  }
  fs.writeFileSync('case.json' JSON.stringify(updatedObj))
} catch (e) {
  // do something here with your error.
}
```

This allows your configuration object to have multiple properties if you need them later, and not just `cases`.

---

Note that this is *not* how I would solve this.  I would use `Promise` or `async-await` code instead of either the sync or async styles of `fs`.  But this is a quick fix of your original problem in a similar style.